# Initializing a Repository with Google Cloud SDK

Tags: git, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am setting up the project for a Chrome Extension using the Google Developers Console. I installed the Google Cloud SDK without a problem, but when I try to run `gcloud init my-extension-111` in the folder of my extension, I get the following error message:

```
Initialized gcloud directory in [C:\_Projects\my-extension-111\.gcloud].
Cloning [https://source.developers.google.com/p/my-extension-111/r/default] into [default].
ERROR: Unable to initialize project [my-extension-111], cleaning up [C:\_Projects\my-extension-111].
ERROR: <gcloud.init> Cannot find git. PLease install git and try again.

You can find git installers at [http://git-scm.com/downloads], or use
your favorite package manager to install it on your computer.
```

This doesn't make any sense to me as I have had git installed on my computer for ages, and even ran `git init` from git bash in the folder of my extension. Could someone please help me fix this error so I can upload my source to GCloud? Thanks in advance.

Comment: git path is in PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the way git is installed on your computer does not place it onto your system path. Specifically, `git bash` is a special shell that has git on the system path, but that does not put it on the system path for any other tools.

gcloud and cmd.exe both look for commands using the PATH environment variable.  If you can run git by starting cmd.exe and typing git, it should be case that glcoud will be able to find it too.

Try starting cmd.exe, typing `git` and seeing if the command is found.  If not, add the directory containing git to to `PATH`, and try again.  (You may need to restart.)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on my WIN 7 pc using the "Google Cloud SDK Shell".
I had git in my PATH, but only the "..git/cmd" folder. Which worked ok for all normal git operations.

I added the "..git/bin" folder into PATH to get it to work with gcloud

> path C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;%PATH%
>
> gcloud init my-extension-111

A later update of git to version 1.9 solved this problem permanently